# Drawing a polygon using Path and a List of Points

Tags: android, path, draw

Hey I'm trying to draw a polygon with vertices as a List of Points. In my class, my List of Points is called rep. I'm not very familiar with Path but this is the code I'm using to (attempt) to draw it

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint){
    path.reset();
    if (type != TYPE_CIRCLE) {
        path.moveTo(rep.get(0).x, rep.get(0).y);
        for(int i = 1; i < rep.size(); i++){
            path.lineTo(rep.get(i).x, rep.get(i).y);
            path.moveTo(rep.get(i).x, rep.get(i).y);
        }
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    else{
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, paint);
    }
}
```

However nothing gets drawn (not on screen that is, and all points should be within the screen size. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint){
    path.reset();
    if (type != TYPE_CIRCLE) {
        path.moveTo(rep.get(0).x, rep.get(0).y);
        for(int i = 1; i < rep.size(); i++){
            path.lineTo(rep.get(i).x, rep.get(i).y);
        }
        path.lineTo(rep.get(0).x, rep.get(0).y);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    else{
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, paint);
    }
}
```